# CSS clip-path with inline SVG not working

Tags: css, svg

I'm not sure why this is not working. It should clip the green rectangle on a diagonal. If possible, I would prefer not to change my html structure (changing the SVG is fine).

```css
.el-to-clip{
  clip-path: url(#nav-path);
  width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
  <clipPath id="nav-path" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <polygon points="0 0, 73 0, 100 100, 0 100"></polygon>
   </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
  
<div class="el-to-clip"></div>
```

Comment: Aha! That was the answer. Thank you very much. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Any clue why it doesn't work in edge, though?

Comment: I'm not sure you can clip html content with Edge, I think it only supports clipping SVG elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

objectBoundingBox units are in the range 0..1 Perhaps you meant .73 and 1 as below.

```css
.el-to-clip{
  clip-path: url(#nav-path);
  width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
  <clipPath id="nav-path" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <polygon points="0 0, .73 0, 1 1, 0 1"></polygon>
   </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
  
<div class="el-to-clip"></div>
```